# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'CGFloat *' (aka 'float *') from 'int'

Tags: ios, pointers, uiscrollview, cgfloat

I'm having a problem with `CGFloat`. What I am trying to do is to set a value for the X of a `UIScrollView` to do some actions when the user change page using a `UIButton` to do that.

This is the error Xcode gives to me:

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'CGFloat *' (aka 'float *') from 'int'
```

This is my code:

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{

}

@property (nonatomic)                       CGFloat         *offsetPoint;
@property (weak, nonatomic)     IBOutlet    UIScrollView    *trackSelectionScrollView;

@end
```

**.m**

```
- (void)scrollForward
{
    self.offsetPoint = self.trackSelectionScrollView.contentOffset.x; // Error here

    if ((self.offsetPoint = 0)) // Error here
    {
        [self.trackSelectionScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0) animated:YES];
    }

    if ((self.offsetPoint = 320)) // Error here
    {
        [self.trackSelectionScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(640, 0) animated:YES];
    }

    if ((self.offsetPoint = 640)) // Error here
    {
        //Last page do nothing
    }
}
```

If you can't understand the problem with the code I've posted I will post more of it :-)

Comment: Basically, it's warning you that you're attempting to assign an integer to a pointer.  You shouldn't do that.  (The type of the pointer is something of a red herring -- the error would occur with *any* pointer type.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> @property (nonatomic)                       CGFloat         *offsetPoint;

This property is storing a pointer to a float and it shouldn't be. Change it to:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat offsetPoint;
```

Comment: Wow that was FAST! Thank you :-)